# close ttyACM0 takes 30 seconds (too slow)

Tags: usb, serial

Raspberry Pi 4 B pPython code basically does this:

```
fptr = open('/dev/ttyACMwa', 'rb')
... etc ...
fptr is used by AsyncReader
... etc ...
```

on shutdown:

```
loginf("before close")
TT1 = time.time()
fptr.close()
TT2 = time.time()
loginf("after  close took {} sec".format(TT2 - TT1))
```

**problem:**
loginf reports 30 seconds (this is a driver so shutdown of service takes 30 seconds to one minute ... too long !!!!)

AsyncReader runs in a thread and this is the main part:

```
    def run(self):
        logdbg("start async reader for %s" % self.getName())
        self._running = True
        for line in iter(self._fd.readline, ''):
            line = line.rstrip()
            # all our files are binary                                                              
            line = line.decode()
            if line:
                self._queue.put(line)
            if not self._running:
                break
```

`/dev/ttyACMwa` is a symbolic link to one of the `/dev/ttyACM0` ... `/dev/ttyACM4` files.
`/dev/ttyACMwa` is created by a `udev` rule.
the device is an Arduino, an Adafruit `itsy` `bitsy` M4; MCU (microcontroller) is ATSAMD51;
it is set to 9600 baud;
there are no hubs; it is a straight connection from Raspberry Pi USB A port to micro USB port on Arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following advice of Dmitry Grigoryev, instead of just opening 'ttyACMx' use

```
_fptr_thpusb = serial.Serial(self._fname_thpusb, timeout);
```

Also do not read from the file descriptor `_fptr_thpusb` unless it has data as determined by

```
ready,_,_ = select.select([self._fd], [], [], timeout);
```

See code marked by "#solution"; this does not block because read always has data;

```
class AsyncReader(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, fd, queue1, label):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._fd = fd
        self._queue = queue1
        self._running = False
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self.setName(label)

    def run(self):
        self._running = True
        # for line in iter(self._fd.readline, ''):                                                  
        while self._running:
            # added --------                                                                      
            timeout = 10
            # this is the solution
            ready,_,_ = select.select([self._fd], [], [], timeout)
            if not ready:
                continue
            line = self._fd.readline()
            # added --------                                                                       
            line = line.rstrip()
            # all our files are binary                                                              
            line = line.decode()
            if not line:
                continue
            self._queue.put(line)

    def stop_running(self):
        self._running = False


class ProcManager(object):
   def startup(self, fname_thpusb, cmd, path=None, ld_library_path=None):
            self._process = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '),
                                             env=env,
                                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            # self._fptr_thpusb = open(self._fname_thpusb, "rb")                                    
            timeout = 5
            # this is the solution
            self._fptr_thpusb = serial.Serial(self._fname_thpusb, timeout)
            self.thpusb_reader = AsyncReader(
                self._fptr_thpusb, self.merge_out_queue, "thp-thread")
            self.thpusb_reader.start()
            self.stdout_reader = AsyncReader(
                self._process.stdout, self.merge_out_queue, "stdout-thread")
            self.stdout_reader.start()
            self.stderr_reader = AsyncReader(
                self._process.stderr, self.stderr_queue, 'stderr-thread')
            self.stderr_reader.start()

      def shutdown(self):
        self._process.kill()
        # originally close() was before the shutdown of the readers                
        self.thpusb_reader.stop_running()
        self.thpusb_reader.join(0.5)
        self.stdout_reader.stop_running()
        self.stdout_reader.join(0.5)
        self.stderr_reader.stop_running()
        self.stderr_reader.join(0.5)
        # originally this was before the shutdown of the readers                   
        self._fptr_thpusb.close()
        self._process.stdout.close()
        self._process.stderr.close()
        if self._process.poll() is None:
            logerr('process did not respond to kill, shutting down anyway')
        self._process = None
        if self.thpusb_reader.is_alive():
            loginf('timed out waiting for %s' % self.thpusb_reader.getName())
        self.thpusb_reader = None
        if self.stdout_reader.is_alive():
            loginf('timed out waiting for %s' % self.stdout_reader.getName())
        self.stdout_reader = None
        if self.stderr_reader.is_alive():
            loginf('timed out waiting for %s' % self.stderr_reader.getName())
        self.stderr_reader = None
        loginf('shutdown complete')
    def get_stderr(self):
        lines = []
        while not self.stderr_queue.empty():
            # lines.append(self.stderr_queue.get().decode())                                        
            lines.append(self.stderr_queue.get())
        return lines
    def get_stdout(self):
        lines = []
        while self.running():
            try:
                # Fetch the output line. For it to be searched, Python 3                            
                # requires that it be decoded to unicode. Decoding does no                          
                # harm under Python 2:                                                              
                # line = self.merge_out_queue.get(True, 3).decode()                                 
                line = self.merge_out_queue.get(True, 3)
                m = ProcManager.TS.search(line)
                if m and lines:
                    yield lines
                    lines = []
                lines.append(line)
            except queue.Empty:
                yield lines
                lines = []
        yield lines
```

Comment: Please [edit] and put any additional info in the answer and *not* in the comments. Comments are ephemeral in nature and tends to get deleted after a while. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your thread is not stuck in the `readline` call when you close the file. And not just set the `_running` flag to False, but actually make sure the thread joined back.

Perhaps a more practical advice is to use `pyserial` which already handles timeouts properly (using `select`).